# Conveniently inserting custom text in table headers generated by pander

Tags: r, string, dataframe, pander

I'm generating a simple table in pander. I would like to have a greater control over the text that appears as a header. For example the code below:

````
---
title: "OddFile"
author: "Test"
date: "November 18, 2015"
output: pdf_document
---

Amazing table

```{r sourceDescribeIndicators, echo=FALSE, eval=TRUE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, cache=TRUE}
library(datasets)
data(mtcars)
require(reshape2)
mtcars$nme <- rownames(mtcars)
mtc_melt <- melt(data = mtcars, id.vars = c("nme"))

# Pander
require(pander)
pander(data.frame("Available Models" = unique(mtc_melt$nme)))
```
````

Would generate the following table:

[image: pander table]

The data frame transformation applied to the generated vector of unique values results in **Available Models** being transformed to **Available.Models** as the `make.names` function would return the same result. How can I conveniently work around it? I'm interested in a solution that would enable me to use strings that are not syntactically correct when generating tables via `pander`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a `pander` issue, but `data.frame` calls `make.names` internally by default, but you can override this behavior by the `check.names` argument, eg:

```
> pander(head(data.frame("Available Models" = unique(mtc_melt$nme), check.names = FALSE)))

------------------
 Available Models 
------------------
    Mazda RX4     

  Mazda RX4 Wag   

    Datsun 710    

  Hornet 4 Drive  

Hornet Sportabout 

     Valiant      
------------------
```